# How to get a resonator working instead of a crystal in simple AT89c51 blink LED circuit?

Tags: led

I have got the blink LED example working perfectly for the at89c51 MCU which uses two 22pf capacitors and a 12 Mhz crystal in the circuit

[image]
the above circuit is given at the tutorial at

https://electrosome.com/led-blinking-8051-microcontroller-keil-c-tutorial-at89c51/

I am simply replacing the crystal in the above circuit with a 455Khz  (2 pin) resonator which is this component here

https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/products/detail/ecs-inc./ZTB455E/251697

but it does not work work at all. So what do I need to get this resonator working instead of using a crystal in this simple blinking LED circuit?

Comment: Did you change the capacitors to the recommended value of 100pF each?  Does the AT89C51 have an option for an internal RC clock, with no crystal?

Comment: @TimWescott As far as I am aware it does not need fuse bits settings for setting (if that is what you mean by your comment) an  option for resonator. The internal oscillator doesnt work without an external crystal or resonator.

I also tried it using an arduino as a clock (0.5 Mhz and 1Mhz) and it worked
perfectly as expected.

I also replaced the 12 Mhz crystal with a 4Mhz crystal and it works perfectly as
expected but slower blinking.

Comment: @TimWescott I tried the ceramic resonator with 471, 681 and 22pf capacitors and no capacitors  in all possible combinations and it didn't work

Comment: @TimWescott Actually the circuit still works without the 22pf capacitors and using the 12 Mhz crystal only.

Comment: The resonator needs 100 pF capacitors as stated by Tim.

Comment: @Andyaka So it doesn't need the 1 Mohm resistor and diode for the 455Khz resonator? as shown here http://electronbunker.ca/eb/SignalGen455.html

Comment: @Andyaka the 471 and 681 are the nearest capacitors I had -I wasn't aware it needed to be exactly 100pf. I will see if I can find some capacitors that value to pull out from old gadgets.

Comment: That's not a diode; it's the inverting gate inside your chip. Here's a [tear down](http://www.stades.co.uk/XTAL%20Oscillator/XTAL%20Oscillator.html) on how crystal oscillators work (which also applies to resonators). The 1Mohm should be inside your chip too; it biases the inverting gate (inside the chip) into linear mode.

Comment: @Andyaka Ok so it not a dioide. In the datasheet the inverting gate can be a CMOS CD4069 (which can be thought of to have a built in resistor). I don't think a CD 4069 is required (it only requires the two 100pf capacitors as mentioned above)  though for the at89c51 blink circuit still interesting to know though.

Comment: @Andyaka I maybe able to get some more 22pf capacitors and five 22 pf capacitors in parallel makes 110pf which unfortunately is 10pf too many